# Encryption method used for snaplogic Accounts(SMTP,basic auth)

Tags: snaplogic

By using snaplogic read snap we can get account details and its passwords.

Actual thing is response from snaplogic read snap contain the passwords which are encrypted. Thing i needed is decryption method for passowrd.

Comment: Even if you know the decryption "method", from where will you get the key?

Comment: I want to know only the decryption method. Decrypting message is second thing.

Answer (score 0):

With the public key, you can use it to encrypt the sensitive fields in Snaplogic
account. 
The encryption algorithm used for "short" values is "RSA-OAEP" with
"SHA-256" as the hash. If the value is zero-length or not "short" (more than 100
bytes), then the property needs to be encrypted with AES, since \ OAEP
algorithm can only encrypt a fixed amount of data.

When encrypting with AES,a 256-bit key must be generated along with an IV and used with AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding algorithm to encrypt the property value. The AES key
is then encrypted with the RSA-OAEP algorithm.

An encrypted account with only asymmetric encryption (i.e. RSA-OAEP) should
contain the following fields:
  value: The base64-encoded encryption of the utf8-encoded property value.
  key: The alias of the public key used to do the encryption.

If the property is encrypted with an AES key, the property should contain the
additional fields:
  sym_iv: The base64-encoded IV used to do the symmetric encryption.
  sym_key: The base64-encoded AES key used to do the symmetric encryption.